# UITextField change rightview size with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitextfield

I am trying to create a custom `UITextField` with search bar behavior, when the `UITextField` is focused, a button from the right will move in and the `UITextField` size will them become smaller. And the text in the UITextField should move with animation as well. I tried the following code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^(){
                     self.textField.frame = newFrame;
                     self.textField.rightView.frame = anotherNewFrame;
                 }];
```

My question is, the textfield change the size with animation with no problem. However, the rightView does not change size with animation, the text in the `UITextField` simply JUMPS to the final position. How can I animate the shifting for the text?

### update

Add these two lines in viewDidLoad

```
self.textfield.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self.textfield.rightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

And in UITextField delegate method textFieldDidBeginEditing

```
CGRect frame = self.textfield.frame;
frame.size.width = frame.size.width - 50.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^(){
                     self.textfield.frame = frame;
                 }];
```

Still cannot get the effect desired, the text inside the textfield still jumps when the textfield changes its width with animation. I also tried

```
UIView *dummy = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
dummy.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
self.textfield.rightView = dummy;
```

no luck.

Comment: I think you don't need to change the rightView frame as far if you not changing the width and height, if it shifts with the change of the parent textfield, just you need to use `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`.

Comment: I put this line `self.textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;` in viewDidLoad, the text still jumps with not animation.

Comment: No, put this for the `rightView` not `textfield`. And don't animated the rightView, animate only the TextField.

Comment: @iphonic, would you please see the update for the sample code I tried? Still no luck for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the code below, it should work..

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self toggleRightView:YES];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self toggleRightView:NO];
    return YES;
}


-(void)toggleRightView:(BOOL)show{
    if(show){
        self.txtField.rightViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] init];
        CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 30.0);
        //Place the rightview toward the right side of the textfield.
        rect.origin.x=self.txtField.frame.size.width-rect.size.width;
        view.frame=rect;
        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        self.txtField.rightView=view;
        view.alpha=0.0;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            CGRect frame=self.txtField.frame;
            frame.size.width=frame.size.width+100.0;
            self.txtField.frame=frame;
            self.txtField.rightView.alpha=1.0;

        }];
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            CGRect frame=self.txtField.frame;
            frame.size.width=170.0;
            self.txtField.frame=frame;
            self.txtField.rightView.alpha=0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.txtField.rightView removeFromSuperview];
            self.txtField.rightView=nil;
        }];
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Tried your code, I could see the `rightView` shifted with animation, but the text still does not :(